# ¿Cómo puedo desplegar un estado de carga que desaparezca cuando una petición await axios.get termine?

Tags: botón, axios, onclick

Se tiene el siguiente código:

```
<button onClick=
   {async ()=> {
      try{
         const res = await axios.get('/api/movility_restrictions/2val');
         if (res.status === 200) {
            confirm('Operación finalizada correctamente');
         }else{
            confirm('Error en la operación');
         }
      }catch(error){
         console.log(error.response.data)
         confirm(error.response.data.message);
      }> Actualizar cuotas </button>
```

Mientras se ejecuta la petición axios.get se requiere desplegar un estado de carga que desaparezca cuando finalice dicha petición.

Comment: Muy sencillo, antes de la linea que llama a `axios` debes establecer tu estado de carga, que no indicas en tu pregunta cuál es. Supongamos que se llama `isFetching`, entonces basta con usar: `setIsFetching(true)`. Luego podrías usar un bloque `finally`, en el cual vuelves a establecer tu estado a `false`. Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Además, es importante que leas [mre].

Comment: Muchas gracias. Con lo que indicas se puede determinar cuándo terminar el estado de carga, sin embargo, me haría falta también el cómo desplegar visualmente un estado de carga (Loading, spinner o un simple texto que diga cargando...) y que luego lo pueda remover en el finally.

Comment: Por favor agrega lo que has intentado. Puedes añadir un [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de varios intentos logré hacer lo que necesitaba. Bloquear la página mientras la petición se estaba realizando. Si bien no despliego un mensaje, sí se bloquea el contenido. A continuación, el código:

```
function ValidateButton(){
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
   const [data, setData] = useState(null);
   const [error, setError] = useState(null);

   const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setData(null);
    setError(null);

    try {
       const res2 = await axios.get('/api/movility_restrictions/2val');
       setData(res2.data);
       if (res2.status === 200) {
          console.log('Actualización exitosa')
       }else{
          console.log('Error en la actualización')
       }
    } catch (error) {
        setError(error.response.data);
    } finally {
        setLoading(false);
        confirm('Las cuotas fueron actualizadas de acuerdo al pico y placa registrado');
    }
};

return(
    <div className="grid gap-1 grid-cols-2" style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
        {loading && (
            <div
                style={{
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                    zIndex: 9999,
                    pointerEvents: 'auto', // Allow clicks to pass through overlay
                    cursor: 'wait', // Change cursor to wait while loading
                }}
            />
        )}
        <button className="text-gray-700 font-bold bg-white rounded-lg border-gray-800 mb-3 p-4 hover:gb-gray-100 hover:cursor-pointer" 
            onClick={fetchData} disabled={loading}
        > {loading ? 'Procesando...' : 'Actualizar cuotas'} </button>
    </div>
)
```

}